# Prepared Statements MYSQL to MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql

How do i change the following outdated line of code into a prepared statement, i have attempted via reading some tutorials but i cant seem to comprehend?

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from asset_records WHERE a_catagory LIKE '%Desktop%' GROUP BY a_make;") or die(mysql_error());  


                while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo "<a href='index.php? sc1=Desktop & sc2=a_make  & sc3=". $row['a_make'] ."'>";
                    echo ' <span> ' . $row['a_make'] . '</span></a></td></li>'; } 
                    echo "</ul></li>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see how far you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PDO (if you change your mind):

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=your_host;dbname=your_db",$user,$pass);

$query = "SELECT * FROM asset_records WHERE a_category LIKE '%Desktop%' GROUP BY a_make";
$result = $connection->prepare($query);
$result->execute();


 while($row = $result->fetch()) {
     // DATA HERE
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, should i use PDO over MYSQLI would you say? @Daan

Comment: That really depends on your needs. PDO works with multiple drivers.

Comment: Thanks, just read a tasty artical about PDO, looks much better for migration purposes, the connection to the DB will still need to be hidden outside the root of HTDOCS right?,

Answer (score 3):

Typically, prepared statements are used when user input is to be accepted.

In this case, you aren't accepting any user input and therefore a standard query is all you'll need, as there's no risk of SQL Injection.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from asset_records WHERE a_catagory LIKE '%Desktop%' GROUP BY a_make");
if($result):
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
        echo '<li>';
        echo "<a href='index.php? sc1=Desktop & sc2=a_make  & sc3=". $row['a_make'] ."'>";
        echo ' <span> ' . $row['a_make'] . '</span></a></td></li>'; } 
        echo "</ul></li>";
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Just a note, but I find that `$result->fetch_assoc()` to be cleaner. Still a good answer tho.